# Scrollbar disappears due to background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm a new-bee and I am trying to build a web-page which has a **background image throughout the application**.

Problem is that when I move further in the application after login page and all, there is a page called *family details* which has a scroll-able content but due to the background image the scroll bar does not appear.

I've tried using `image tag` instead of using background image but then the content does not appear over the image, it appears below the image.

**App.component.html**

```
<div class="background-image">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
.background-image {
    background-image: url('assets/icf.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

With image tag

**App.component.html**

```
<img src="assets/icf.jpg" alt="/">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: dont think this is due to the background image. where is your code from family details??

Comment: There is no problem in the code of family details because i tried to run the application after removing the background image and it worked fine,i.e the scroll-bar appeared in the page of family details.

Comment: Put the image in the index.html

Comment: its quite hard to help you with only this info. if you could show a minified reproducable problem it would be easier

Comment: @akberiqbal tried that, content appears below the image but not over the image.

Comment: @DigitalJedi, actually the family details code is quite long.

Comment: @YashAnand, i added code, description and working stackblitz below as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your image tag method, and assign a lower `z-index` to the `img` tag, than the rest of the content

```
<img src="assets/icf.jpg" alt="/" style="z-index: 0;">
<div class ="all-your-other-stuff" style="z-index: 1;"></>
```

```css
.img{
background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/200x200");
z-index: 0;
height: 200px;
width: 200px;
}

.content{

z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
<div class="content">TEXT ABOVE IMAGE</div>
```

Comment: content still appears below the image :(

Comment: see my fiddle, that this is working, as I said, a **minified** reproduction of your problem would help

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/200x200');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Test data</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Try adding image on Body tag using background-image and use repeat-x, repeat-y property from css.

Then the image will be at the background always.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to the index.html, and make sure that the div which houses your angular code has a higher z-index; relevant **index.html** below:

```
 <div class='bkgClass'>
    <div class='insideClass'>
        <my-app>loading</my-app>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .bkgClass {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background: url("https://beta.akberiqbal.com/JumboMobT.JPG");
    }

    .insideClass {
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>
```

No change to your **app.component**, or any other components;

you can check a [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lcgpy4)